# React FullCalendar not showing allDay event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using FullCalendar 5.11 in React. Non-all-day events are showing up, but all-day events are not.

Here's the FullCalendar setup:

```
                <FullCalendar
                    height='100%'
                    width='50px'
                    initialView='timeGridDay'
                    allDaySlot={true}
                    plugins={[ timeGridPlugin ]}
                    events={ events }
                    eventMaxStack={ 1 }
                    nowIndicator={true}
                    eventClick={ eventClickHandler }
                    headerToolbar={ headerToolbar }
                    titleFormat={{ year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }}
                />
```

The calendar renders correctly, and there's the all day slot at the top.

Here's an example of an event that shows up correctly:

```
{id: 'tvid6bu8mbqphkqig7qooline0', title: 'Test 30min event', backgroundColor: '#000000', start: '2020-05-12T01:30:00.000Z', end: '2020-05-12T02:00:00.000Z'}
```

Here's an example of an all-day event that doesn't show up:

```
{id: '64rjv5muo12ha2ih4al3caajue', title: 'Test all day event', backgroundColor: '#fbe983', allDay: true, startStr: '2022-08-23'}
```

In the allDay json, including `endStr` or using instead `start` and `end` both don't fix the issue. I've tried an `endStr` or `end` that are one day or two days after the start too.

Moreover, I searched the HTML of the page - it's not that the all day event is just hidden somewhere.

Can anybody help me spot what I'm missing here?

Comment: `or using instead start and end both don't fix the issue`... I disagree - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRxLyLy . The event you say doesn't show up, shows up fine if you simply change `startStr` to `start`. If you look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing it shows clearly which property names fullCalendar recognises for each purpose.

Comment: P.S. There is no such setting as "width" in fullCalendar, please take a look here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `start` and `end` not `startStr` or `endStr`

`end` is not required though

try changing your JSON

```
{
  id: '64rjv5muo12ha2ih4al3caajue',
  title: 'Test all day event',
  backgroundColor: '#fbe983',
  allDay: true,
  start: '2022-08-23'
}
```

[image: example working in codepen]

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! Thought I tried that combination. Thanks